# react-router-dom v4 routing with guest and authorized routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I cant seem to understand the proper way of dealing with guest and authorized routes. I checked out the given example https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow but that dosnt block the authorized user to open /login route and it seems all of the given examples do the same.

I tried doing something like this:

```
export default function requireGuest(WrappedComponent) {

class Guest extends Component {

    render() {
        if (this.props.authenticated) {
            return <Redirect to="/agenda"/>
        }

        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {authenticated: isLoggedInSelector(state)}
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {pure: false});

return compose(
    withConnect,
    withRouter
)(Guest);

}

class Authorized extends Component {

    render() {

        if (!this.props.authenticated) {
            return <Redirect to="/login"/>
        }

        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {authenticated: isLoggedInSelector(state)}
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {pure: false});

return compose(
    withConnect,
    withRouter
)(Authorized);

}
```

And then in the main container do something like this:

```
<Route path='/login' component={RequireGuest(LoginPage)}/>
<Route path='/register' component={RequireGuest(RegisterPage)}/>
<Route path="/dashboard" component={RequireAuthorization(DashboardPage)}/>
```

But when i try to navigate anywhere else the path updates and the state updates too, but there is no rerenders and no redirects.

Then I tried something like this:

```
class GuestRoutes extends Component {

render() {

    const {loggedIn} = this.props;

    return (
        <Route
            render={props =>
                loggedIn ? (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/agenda",
                            state: {from: props.location}
                        }}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage}/>
                        <Route path='/register' component={RegisterPage}/>
                        <Redirect to='/login'/>
                    </Switch>
                )
            }
        />
    );

}
}

class AuthorizedRoutes extends Component {

render() {

    const {loggedIn} = this.props;

    return (
        <Route
            render={props =>
                loggedIn ? (
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage}/>
                            <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
                        </Switch>
                    ) :
                    (<Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/login",
                            state: {from: props.location}
                        }}
                    />)
            }
        />
    );

}
}
```

And in the main container

```
<Switch>
    <GuestRoutes/>
    <AuthorizedRoutes/>
</Switch>
```

But then if the user is logged in, the guest routes keep getting rendered until it gets the depth error.

Im been trying to figure this out for quite a few hours so im getting desperate here. So any examples or anything that has routes protected based on the authorization state

Comment: can u try using `this.props.history.push('/login')` instead of <Redirect/>

Comment: Now I get these errors

Comment: Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor) and Uncaught Error: Route(...): Nothing was returned from render.

Comment: Could you provide your code in codepen (https://codepen.io/) or something like that?